(TraceBack (most recent call last)):Error When Trying to Download en_core_web_md from spacy in CommandPrompt
I recently started a tutorial on nlp and we i reached word vectors, the spacy library was required specifically en_core_web_md the , in this part i keep getting this error (when i try to download en_core_web_md from spacy it always returns this error)
I use the command python -m spacy download en_core_web_mdin command Prompt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 406, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 87, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 783, in main
    return _main(
           ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 225, in _main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 43, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 77, in download
    compatibility = get_compatibility()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 122, in get_compatibility
    r = requests.get(about.__compatibility__)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 532, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)

I have not tried any thing since i cant find any solution online
other than asking AI but it says i should check  my internet connection and there is nothing wrong with my network. the other option was to download it directly from the website
can some one help me with another solution

Ok i was able to fix the problem so if any one is dealing with the same error download en_core_web_md(this applies both small and large) directly from the spacy website [https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_md]

After the download un zip the file (i used 7-Zip for this)
-the Directly In your code you import ht file like so
'import spacy
model_path = "C:/somthin/somthing/Downloads/en_core_web_md-3.7.1-py3-none-any/en_core_web_md/en_core_web_md-3.7.1"

Load the model from the directory path
nlp = spacy.load(model_path)'
-And we are don
